# Удаленный доступ к PostgreSQL без SSH Tunnel

Tags: postgresql

Имеется удаленный сервер на Debian, который находится не в локальной сети. На него установил postgres, добавил пользователя и базу данных. Дал права пользователю на эту бд. Изменил файлы pg_hba.conf и postgresql.conf соответственно. Подключиться со своего компа могу в pgAdmin только с использованием SSH Tunnel(указывая свои данные учетной записи на Debian). Но мне нужно подключатся без SSH Tunnel, т.к. хочу использовать бд в своем nodejs проекте. Как я могу этого добиться? Рестарт делаю командой `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

pg_hba.conf

```
 host    all     all             0.0.0.0/0                 trust
```

postgresql.conf

```
 listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

netstat -ntpua | grep 5432

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Какую проблему наблюдаете? Какая ошибка подключения? Не делайте trust, строго никогда не делайте trust на весь мир.

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо, поменял на password

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто открыть порт 5432 на сервере

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp —dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```